# Is it possible to assign colours to each plot produced through the lmplot "col" function?

Tags: seaborn

I would like to assign each plot a seperate colour, consistent with the aggregate graph produced through the hue function.

```
sns.lmplot(x="AvgT", y="kWh", hue="Condition", data=df, palette="Set1");
```

Creates:
[image: hue graphic]

However, this doesn't work for the col function:

```
sns.lmplot(x="AvgT", y="kWh", col="Condition", data=df, palette="Set1");
```

Creates:
[image: col graphic]

I would like the first graph to be red, the second blue and the third green so the two figures are directly relatable. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is!

```
sns.lmplot(x="AvgT", y="kWh", hue= "Condition", col="Condition", data=df, palette="Set1");
```

[image]